# For an abelian group G, the induced map $H_{\bullet}(G.M)$ is the identiy

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I have this question for the proof of a lemma I was reading.

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $M$ a $G$-module with that I have the question about this part:

"Since e $G$ is an abelian group it's well known that for any $g\in G$, the map $g:M\rightarrow M$ induces identity homomorphism on all homology groups."

I assume that the map from above it is the multiplication by $g$. Now I was trying the next thing (The idea is from the chapter 3, section VIII of Kenneth Brown Group Cohomology).

Since $G$ is abelian the map $\alpha=id:G\rightarrow G$ satisfy that the map $g:M\rightarrow M$ is compatible with $\alpha$; i.e. $g(hm)=\alpha(h)g(m)$. Now if $F$ is a the bar resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}G$, the map $\tau:F\rightarrow F$ given by $\tau(x)=g^{-1}x$ is a chain map compatible with $\alpha$.

Therefore I have the chain map $\tau\otimes g:F\otimes_{G} M\rightarrow F\otimes_{G} M$ given by $x\otimes m\mapsto g^{-1}x\otimes gm$.

We have that $F$ is also a right $G$-module but since $G$ is abelian, we have that $gx=xg$ for all $x\in F$ and $g\in G$. Thus $g^{-1}x\otimes gm=xg^{-1}\otimes gm=x(g^{-1}g)\otimes m=x\otimes m$

Thus this chain map is the identity and therefore induces identity homomorphism on all homology groups.

That's the only idea I could think, Is that correct, specially the last part where I assume that $F$ is also a right module.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You show that $\tau \otimes g$ induces the identity on homology, but you want to show that $1\otimes g$ induces the identity on homology.  I do not see anything in your argument that implies these maps are the same on homology.  I have posted a brute force calculation below, proving the required result.

Answer (score 1):

Tensoring the inhomogeneous bar resolution with M we obtain a sequence of abelian groups:$$\cdots \stackrel{d}\to M^{G\times G\times G}
\stackrel{d}\to M^{G\times G}
\stackrel{d}\to M^{G}
\stackrel{d}\to M\to 0.
$$

For $m\in M$ and $g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_k\in G$, let  $[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]\in M^{G^k}$ be the element with co-ordinate $m$ on the summand $M$ corresponding to $(g_1,\cdots,g_k)$ and all other co-ordinates $0$.  Then the above differentials are given by: $$d\colon[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]\mapsto
$$
$$
[g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]-[g_kg_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]+[g_k,g_{k-1}g_{k-2},\cdots,g_1,m]-\cdots +(-1)^k[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1m]
$$
The maps induced by multiplication by $h\in G$ are given by: $$h_*\colon[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]\mapsto[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,hm].$$
These are isomorphisms of abelian groups, regardless of $G$ being abelian.  However, if $h$ is central in $G$ then $h_*$ is a chain map.  That is, if $h$ is central in $G$ then $h_*d=dh_*$ as $hg_1=g_1h$.

We define $I\colon M^{G^k}\to M^{G^{k+1}}$ for each $k\geq 0$ by:
$$
I\colon [g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]\mapsto
$$
$$
[h,g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]-[g_k,h,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]+\cdots+(-1)^k[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,h,m].
$$

Again assume that $h$ is central in $G$.  The key result is: $$dI+Id=1-h_*.\qquad\qquad[1]$$

To see this, consider $(dI+Id)[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]$ and note that all terms of $Id [g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]$ are cancelled out by the corresponding term in $dI[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]$.

The remaining terms in $dI[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]$ of the form $\pm [g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,hg_r,\cdots,g_1,m]$ and $\mp [g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_rh,\cdots,g_1,m]$ cancel out, as $h$ is central in $G$.  This leaves the two desired terms:$$(dI+Id)[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]=[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,m]-[g_k,g_{k-1},\cdots,g_1,hm],$$ and we have proven $[1]$.

Finally note that if $z$ is a cycle, then $dz=0$ so by $[1]$: $$z-h_*z=dIz+Idz=dIz,$$
which is a boundary.  Thus $z$ and $h_*z$ represent the same element in homology.